# Is the Favorite Editor on Developer Story really that important?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

In the summary section of the Developer Story, right below the summary, you have an option to set your Favorite Editor with the text "Vim, Sublime text, Atom?". I know it's an optional field, but I'm curious if it's such an important characteristic of the developer that it deserves to be featured in such a way.
Wouldn't this be better be just part of the favorite tags for instance? I'm very surprised at the relevance that's been given to this info. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Neither "favourite editor" nor "first computer" are terribly important, as such. They're just tidbits allowing for a bit of personal expression that is maybe nice to know, but probably never seriously relevant on either side in a job application.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Agree! I completely skipped "first computer" which seems even more irrelevant!

Comment: But they're nice to have for some. Which is arguably why they're correctly separated from, say, the "I want to work with" tags.